# Daily and Hourly Averages from (m/d/yyyy h:mm) timestamps in Excel

Tags: excel, date, timestamp, excel-2007, average

I have an Excel 2007 spreadsheet with date entries in this format `m/d/yyyy h:mm` (one cell).  I would like find the hourly and daily average of all the columns of this spreadsheet and save each time aggregation to a new worksheet.

The data is recorded every ~10 minutes, but throughout the dates of data collection there was some time slips.  Not every hour has the same number of rows.  Also, the ending minute is either 0 or 6 depending on the time correction.

What would be a good way to approach this task within Excel 2007?  It seems like this might be possible with a pivot table if I can create a formula that will select the correct range for the timestamps.  Thanks.

For example, an date time entry in TIMESTAMP, `10/31/2012 0:06` which is in one cell.

```
TIMESTAMP Month Day Year Hour Min Rain_mm Rain_mm_2 AirTC AirTC_2 FuelM FuelM_2 VW ... there are ~16 variables (total) after the data time
10/31/2012 0:06 10 31 2012 0 06 0 0 26.11 26.08 2.545 6.4 0.049
10/31/2012 0:16 10 31 2012 0 16 0 0 25.98 25.97 2.624 6.6 0.049
10/31/2012 0:26 10 31 2012 0 26 0 0 24.32 23.33 2.543 6.5 0.048
10/31/2012 0:36 10 31 2012 0 36 0 0 24.32 23.33 2.543 6.5 0.048
10/31/2012 0:46 10 31 2012 0 46 0 0 24.32 23.33 2.543 6.5 0.048
10/31/2012 0:56 10 31 2012 0 56 0 0 25.87 25.87 2.753 7.3 0.049
10/31/2012 1:06 10 31 2012 0 06 0 0 25.74 25.74 2.879 8.1 0.051
## The above is just over one hour of collection on one day ##
...    
## Different Day ### Notice Missing Time Stamp
11/30/2012 0:00 11 30 2012 0 06 0 0.1 26.12 26.18 2.535 6.4 0.049
11/30/2012 0:10 11 30 2012 0 16 0 0.1 25.90 25.77 2.424 6.6 0.049
11/30/2012 0:20 11 30 2012 0 26 0.1 0.2 24.12 24.43 2.542 6.4 0.046
11/30/2012 0:30 11 30 2012 0 36 0.1 0 24.22 22.32 2.543 6.5 0.048
11/30/2012 0:50 11 30 2012 0 56 0.1 0.2 26.77 25.87 2.743 6.3 0.049
11/30/2012 1:00 11 30 2012 0 06 0 0 24.34 24.77 2.459 5.1 0.050
## so forth on so on ##
```

Comment: @pnuts They averages you provided are correct and the 7 did not belong.  I have included a more complete data set.  Is there a way to use the data and time to select the interval to average?  Or will I need to know the number of rows for the denominator a priori? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clarification of the requirement for daily averages edited to cover both daily and hourly averages:

1. Add a column (here `B`) for ‘H’ (ie hour) with `=HOUR(A2)` copied down.

(Note: Though formatted to show only m/d/y content of `ColumnA` is, in line with title, assumed to be all of mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm. Makes existing columns [with names jumbled] Month, Day, Year, Hour redundant).

2. Select data range.
3. **Data**, **Subtotal**, **At each change in:** TIMESTAMP, **Use function:** Average, **Add subtotal to:** check only columns `G` and to the right, **OK**.
4. Uncheck **Replace current subtotals** in Subtotal and apply **At each change in:** H, **Use function:** Average, and **Add subtotal to:** *as before*, **OK**.
5. Replace `=SUBTOTAL(1,` in Min column with `=MIN(` .
6. Delete ‘spare’ `Grand Average` row.
7. Reformat as required.

Hopefully this will be achieved and is what is required!:

[image: SO13731807 example]

Note midnight 'tonight' is counted as within first hour of tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar need and worked it out this way:

1. Add a column for **Date** (assuming your dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss data is in cell A2)

   ```
   =DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),DAY(A2))
   ```
2. Add a column for **Year**. If you have weeks from a single year, the year column can be neglected.

   ```
   =YEAR(A2)
   ```
3. Add a column for **Week Number**

   ```
   =WEEKNUM(A2)
   ```
4. Add 2 pivot tables, 1 for daily and 1 for weekly analysis.
5. Choose fields "Date" and the quantities you want. Put "Date" in the **Rows** section and sum/average of values in the **Values** section. You will get a date wise sum/average of the values you need.
6. In the weekly pivot table, do the same as above, just add "Year" and "Week no" in the **Rows** section instead of "Dates" as in above.
   Hope this helps